# How to put log in observer Magento 2

Tags: event-observer, log, debugging, debug

I am trying to put log in observer

sales_order_save_after 
Whenever I put logger in the execute I can’t do any checkout it complains about guest checkout payment 
Is there any other way I could see the log

When I do var_dump it takes me to cart page from checkout because I am stopping the payment

Comment: Could you please share your observer file where you tried logging?

Comment: https://techurbane.com/how-to-add-custom-logs-in-magento-2/

Answer (score 6):

Try Below Code:

Check LoggerInterface to debug

```
<?php
namespace Custom\Module\Observer;

use \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;

class Index implements ObserverInterface
{
     protected $logger;

     public function __construct(
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
                    ) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }
  public function execute(Observer $observer)
  { 

         $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
         // shipping address
         $shippingAddress = $order->getShippingAddress(); 
         $city = $shippingAddress->getCity();
         $country = $shippingAddress->getCountryId();
         $this->logger->info("shippingAddress=>".$country."<");
         $this->logger->info("shippingAddress=>".$city."<");

        }
  }
```

Log print below path:-

> ../var/log/system.log

I hope so it's use full.

Comment: coreSession not been used anywhere is there any reason for that or is that just an accident you have added in the constructor?

Comment: check I have updated my code @jibingeorge

Comment: for some reason to use coreSession

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/custom.log');
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info('=== Your Comment Here ===');
$logger->info('Print Your Value: '.$yourvariable);
$logger->info('=== Your Comment Here ===');
```

Comment: Thank you I will give this one a go too